# Embedded C Programming - IF statement not working properly

Tags: c, embedded

The code below is not working. In this program, if I press Swich1 (PORTK PK1 pin of Arduino Mega), and then if I press Switch2, LED 0 to 3 (which are connected at pins 0 to 3 of port F of Arduino Mega) should blink one by one for each pressing of switch. If I press SW2 switch two times, then while pressing SW1 switch, led 4 to 7 should blink one by one. But the first case is working, whereas the second case is not working.

```
void setup() {

  DDRF =0xFF;
  DDRK = 0x00;
  volatile long i,j,m;
  j=0;
  m=0;
  while (1)
  {
    if ((PINK & 0x02) == 0x02)
    //for(i=0; i<1000; i++) ;
    {
      j=1;
      if (j/2) {
        if ((PINK & 0x01) == 0x01) {
          m++;
          for(i=0; i<50000; i++)
            ;
        }
        if (m==1)
          PORTF =0x01;
        else if(m==2) 
          PORTF=0x02;
        else if(m==3)
          PORTF=0x04;
        else if (m==4) {
          PORTF = 0x08;
          m=0;
        }
      }

      if (j%2) {
        if ((PINK & 0x01) == 0x01)
        // for(i=0; i<20000; i++) ;
        {
          m++;
          for (i=0; i<50000; i++) 
            ; 
        }
        if (m==1)
          PORTF =0x01;
        else if (m==2) 
          PORTF=0x02;
        else if (m==3)
          PORTF=0x04;
        else if (m==4) {
          PORTF = 0x08;
          m=0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Comment: Four close braces on a single line is an indication of gross layout problems in your code.  It is unreadable, and that line alone makes it very hard to see what is going on.  Please use a more orthodox layout style to (dramatically) improve the readability of your code.  See Wikipedia on [Indentation styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style).  I use Allman style; many people prefer 1TBS (One True Brace Style).

Comment: With `if (j/2)` you mean `if (j > 1)`?  As you set `j=1` that `if` condition is never true.  Also, I suggest you reduce code duplication.  Those two if statements have identical bodies.

Comment: You check if PINK's bit 2 is set, then immediate check if bit 1 is set to run the delay loop.  Is there a state change between those two statements?  It's the only way m would be set to something besides the initial `m = 0`.

Comment: You are supposed to respond to questions and requests from comments. Providing readable code will greately improve the chance to attract people willing to help.

Comment: Is there any reason why all your  code is in `setup` function while function `loop` is empty?

Comment: `//for(i=0; i<1000; i++) ;` Commenting code like you do is dangerous. Commenting and uncommenting changes your program flow because it makes the next block after this line either part of the `if` or not. You should urgently put these statements into the block that is part of the `if` and not before it.

Comment: "But the first case is working, whereas the second case is not working." There are no 2 cases in your code. Same thing twice. Remember: Writing readable code is vital also for you.

Comment: How are you debouncing the switch? These kind of questions about switches without any signal debouncing mentioned are very tiresome. Debouncing is typically mentioned in the first couple of beginner classes in embedded programming. TL;DR: if you have no hardware RC filter on this switch, then this program is hopelessly broken and cannot be salvaged.

Comment: You should be aware that Arduino "sketches” are C++, not C.  Your code breaks the sketch framework.  The body of the `while(1)` loop in `setup()` should be in `loop()` without the `while`.  The framework calls `loop()` repeatedly.  That said if you are not going to use the Arduino library for I/O, why use Arduino Sketch at all rather than straight C (or C++)?

Comment: The biggest problem with Arduino is lack of a debugger in most platforms.  You might consider testing and debugging in Tinkercad for example - it simulates the hardware with virtual breadboards and you can step and debug your code.  (Not sure if it simulates switch bounce though).  Your code could stand some simple improvements.  For example consider how many lines could be replaced with `PORTF = 1u << (m - 1) ;`

Comment: The Arduino library has a delay function.  Your busy loops are flawed and may be optimised out.  That said you should avoid delays in Arduino Sketch framework.  It is better to implement `loop()` as a state-machine and poll `millis()` or `micros()` to determine if it is time to change state or perform some action.

Comment: On Arduino Mega, PK1 is nominally analogue input A9.  Not an obvious choice for a digital input, but it can be used as a GPIO by `pinMode( A9, INPUT )`  / `digitalRead( A9 )`; the advantage then being that the code is portable across all Arduino boards rather then being MegaAVR specific.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement works exactly how you would expect - the block is executed it the Boolean expression if `true`, otherwise it does not.  You have *integer* expressions, a non-zero integer expression evaluated as Boolean is `true`, while zero is `false`.

Here:

```
  j=1;
  if (j/2) {  // <<<< ALWAYS FALSE (1/2 == 0)
```

while here:

```
  if (j%2) {  // ALWAYS TRUE (1%2 == 1)
```

The point being that you assign 1 to `j` but never modify it.  The initialisation to zero is never used before `j` is ever tested - it is always 1 when tested.

It is not clear what you intended, but clearly `j` needs to be modified conditionally depending on the switch states.

That is in any case the answer to your question, but the code itself is not "Arduino-friendly".  In the Arduino framework you would normally:

- Use the Arduino library for I/O
- Perform only initialisation in `setup()`
- Do the iterative work in `loop()`
- Allow the framework to do the iteration rather then having an indefinite loop.
- Have the iterative work non-blocking (no busy-wait delays) so that background work can be done.

In this case I would separate the switch detection from both each other and the LED control and use the Arduino I/O.  For example:

```
static const int SW1 = A9 ;
static const int SW2 = A9 ;
static const size_t LED_COUNT = 4u ;
static const int LEDS[2][LED_COUNT] = { { A0, A1, A2, A3 }, 
                                        { A4, A5, A6, A7 } } ;
void setup() 
{
  // Switch inputs
  pinMode( SW1, INPUT ) ;
  pinMode( SW2, INPUT ) ;

  // LED outputs
  for( size_t i = 0; i < LED_COUNT; i++ )
  {
    pinMode( LEDS[0][i], OUTPUT ) ;
    pinMode( LEDS[1][i], OUTPUT ) ;
    digitalWrite( LEDS[0][i], 0 ) ;
    digitalWrite( LEDS[1][i], 0 ) ;
  }
}

void loop() 
{
  static unsigned long led_time = millis() ;
  static unsigned long sw1_time = millis() ;
  static unsigned long sw2_time = millis() ;
  static const int DEBOUNCE_MILLIS = 20 ;
  static const int LED_MILLIS = 500 ;
  static bool previous_sw1_state = digitalRead( SW1 ) != 0 ;
  static bool previous_sw2_state = digitalRead( SW2 ) != 0 ;
  static size_t current_led = LED_COUNT ;
  static size_t current_group = 0 ;

  unsigned long now = millis() ;
  
  // If SW1 state changed (with debounce)...
  bool sw1_state = digitalRead( SW1 ) != 0 ;
  if( now - sw1_time > DEBOUNCE_MILLIS &&
      sw1_state != previous_sw1_state )
  {
    sw1_time = now ;
    previous_sw1_state = sw1_state ;

    // If SW1 pressed and LED cycle not running...
    if( sw1_state && current_led > LED_COUNT)
    {
       // Start LED cycle
       current_led = 0 ;
    }
  }

  // If SW2 state changed (with debounce)...
  bool sw2_state = digitalRead( SW2 ) != 0 ;
  if( now - sw2_time > DEBOUNCE_MILLIS &&
      sw2_state != previous_sw2_state )
  {
    sw2_time = now ;
    previous_sw2_state = sw2_state ;

    // If SW2 pressed and LED cycle not running...
    if( sw2_state && current_led > LED_COUNT )
    {
       // Switch group
       current_group = current_group == 0 ? 1 : 0 ;
    }
  }

  // If LED cycle in progress, and time to switch LED...
  if( current_led <= LED_COUNT && 
      now - led_time > LED_MILLIS  )
  {
    led_time = now ;
    
    // Previous LED off
    if( current_led > 0 )
    {
      digitalWrite( LEDS[current_group][current_led - 1], 0 ) ;
    }

    // Current LED on
    if( current_led < LED_COUNT )
    {
      digitalWrite( LEDS[current_group][current_led], 1 ) ;
    }
    
    // Next LED
    current_led++ ;
  }
}
```

Note that there are no busy-wait delays.  That allows you to do other work in the `loop()` without affecting the timing significantly.

SW1 starts the sequence, and SW2 toggles which group of LEDs the sequence runs on when you next press SW1

Comment: Tested at https://www.tinkercad.com/things/7PvfzuZeCej on Uno with modified I/O.

Comment: @IyyappanChithambarathanu you are welcome, and welcome to SO, but appreciation of an answer is better shown by up-voting and/or marking an answer as accepted.  Messages of thanks are unnecessary and explicitly discouraged.